# Best way to set up dev-env to build windows services?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm about to set out building another windows service, but I know from doing this in the past that because services need to be installed using command line, it makes doing builds not much fun. Is there a way to set up my environment so that after a build, it will automatically re-register the service?

(As a side note: I know you can run command line stuff after a build, but you can't build until the service is unregistered - if the service is still running). So uh, help?

Comment: Customise MSBuild and add <Exec> tasks executing proper command-line stuff.

Comment: Do you know that you can run a Windows service as a console application in the debugger?  [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618277/logic-for-windows-services-getting-updates/13618744#13618744).  That still leaves issues with the account that runs the service, but it sure helps with development.

Comment: I think both edit boxes to enter pre-build commands and post-build commands are on the same page and the same size... Check if see and can use "pre-build event command line" on solution properties' "build events" tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for Topshelf project, it has simplified work with windows services for me.
Also you can run your service in a command line, no need to register it all the time. 
Just read the docs, and maybe you will find the solution that suits your needs.

http://topshelf-project.com
http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html

I have two services that should be started before my webapp. For development i have two console projects with the Topshelf code, so i use multiple startup projects and they both start before the webapp.

For deploying, I just take the console exe file and run install command to install it as normal service, no need to create separate windows service project, and etc.