# Creating a windows services in vb.net(services stuck at starting)

Tags: vb.net, window

i am trying to create a windows.
after i install the services.the status of the services stuck at "starting" instead of started or running.

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

        LoadSettings()

    Catch ex As Exception
        EventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

LoadSettings() method which will draw or pump data from/to database every few seconds.

```
Private Sub LoadSettings()
        Do While 1 = 1
            Dim tStart As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf PumpData)
            tStart.Start()
            tStart.Join(1200000)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Loop
End Sub
```

PumpData method are some sql querys.

Comment: The `OnStart` method should only perform some code to start the service, not to perform the actual work. Also see [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/649948/578843) (C#, but the same applies here).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code:

```
Dim delPeriodicalCheck As New TimerCallback(AddressOf PumpData)
Dim objTimer As System.Threading.Timer
Dim dueTime = 1000 '1 Sec, delay start
Dim period = 60000 '1 Min, you may change this value

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
objTimer = New System.Threading.Timer(delPeriodicalCheck, Nothing, dueTime,period)
Catch ex As Exception
EventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message)
End Try


Private Sub PumpData(ByVal stateInfo As Object)
'Your code
End Sub
```