# Convert a c# program into windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a API (c#) which I have to convert into windows service:

Now the API has a function which we have to call at OnStart()

```
void Start()
{
    while (true)
    {
      //code
    }
    Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(900000);
}
```

So I have coded as:
Service1.cs

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
}
```

Program.cs

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new Service1()
    };
    foreach (ServiceBase sb in ServicesToRun)
    {
        sb.CanPauseAndContinue = false;
        sb.CanShutdown = true;
        sb.CanStop = true;
    }
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Is this way correct or I should modify or need to add something more.

Comment: The OnStart should initialize and start the work (typically on a new thread). It shouldn't do the work. It should do this initialization and return as soon as possible (i.e. very, very quickly). Your OnStart does not look right.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649935/windows-services-onstart-loop-do-i-need-to-delegate

Comment: @hatchet : ok.. i will give it try.. as per link u shared

Comment: I would recommend using a framework for windows service. There are some often overlooked fine points related to properly starting, stopping, shutdown etc., and they should cover that ground for you. There are a number of little frameworks out there on the web for this. The link I gave in the earlier comment has an answer that shows starting a thread. But stopping it is another topic.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add the OnStop Method to deal with cleaning staff  when you stop the service gracefully.

You can write to a log or close open files, write cached data - it all  depends on your actual code, the OnClose function is there to make sure you exit correctly from the service.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) library(it is available via NuGet).
Using TopShelf creating Windows Service as easy as:

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    HostFactory.Run(x =>                                 
    {
        x.Service<TownCrier>(s =>                        
        {
           s.ConstructUsing(name=> new TownCrier());     
           s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());              
           s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());               
        });
        x.RunAsLocalSystem();                            

        x.SetDescription("Sample Topshelf Host");        
        x.SetDisplayName("Stuff");                       
        x.SetServiceName("stuff");                       
    });                                                  
  }
}
```

The great thing about TopShelf is that you can run your program as a plain console application from Visual Studio(F5/ Ctrl-F5) during development.

But when you need to install it as a Windows Service you just need to run your program with *install* argument: *Program.exe install*

Or uninstall it:
*Program.exe uninstall*

Start service:
*Program.exe start*