# C# Windows Service - UDP listener stops service form starter

Tags: c#, service, udp, listener

I am trying to make a service That listens for a UDP packet. And it works fine in debug mode. When I have installed it into the services the problems start. From the OnStart() I run the startListener(). When the listener runs the service stops, when I comment it out and try again it works. 1053 is the error code that pops up.

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private const int listenPort = 9;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        StartListener();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    private static void StartListener()
    {
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
        try
        {
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                string mac = string.Join("", bytes.Skip(6).Take(6).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/649948/1736944

The OnStart event should only get your service running. It isn't a good place to do the actual work.

Error 1053 is the error Windows reports when OnStart fails to return within a set timeout (the default timeout is around 30 seconds).

Comment: DoWork never get's called

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/649948/2468432 Worked Same thing just better explained